# How to correctly load webform using ajax in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

The page I need to make is a bit complex and my team and I face many problems with it.

We need to have a page with multiples sections (just square blocs with text on it). Each section displays (on click) a select. When we click on that select, we have to load a webform using AJAX and here is our problem.

We created a view with a select exposed filter and when we change the select value, a webform is loaded. BUT only the HTML is here, the input masks on the fields are not loaded until we click again on the apply button for loading another webform (or the same as the first one, doesn't matter).

So, how can we correctly load our webform ?

And, even if the masks are loaded on the second load, we don't have our custom handler called when we submit the form. Instead, we are redirect to htp://ourwebsite.com/views/ajax and the custom handler is never called.

Thank you for your time ! :)

Comment: Little confusing to follow the setup. Is the view selection triggering the Ajax req?  Also to get better exposure, I suggest moving the question to DA: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i just posted on drupal.stackexchange and precised the part you didn't understand (Yes, the view selection triggers the ajax req)

Comment: Cool. I just seen that. Hopefully, someone with time will answer it. I’m little busy now.  Also, to help make it easy, post the relevant code and screen shot of squares.  The onClick select is actually coming from views exposed... sounds like